# Securing MS Azure WebApp access at directory level?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-web-app-service

I have a MS Azure ASP.NET Core 2.x WebApp that uses standard Identity based authentication.

I would like to restrict access to the website to only a certain set of people.

I need the entire website to be hidden unless you pass some kind of authorization gate.  The requirement, however, is that the gate should not interfere with the standard ASP.NET Core Identity authentication/authorization mechanisms.

Essentially, we have a website that needs testing by a distributed team, but we don't want the site to be visible to non-members.

TIA!

Comment: If you already have auth in place, why not create a test role, add test users to that role and disable access for everyone else. If it’s a publicly accessible site it’s visible but not accessible. Non authorized users would just see the login page and you can make that non-descript.

Comment: Because there is brand exposure involved and there is a requirement to not allow a half baked site to be visible to any degree.  There's also the issue of search engine indexing, etc.

Comment: Your best bet is going to be using an App Service Environment. If that's too pricey, try the IP restrictions feature on the public app service.

Comment: @JasonP - we went with the IP restrictions, although it did cause some issues with CDN access it was the least intrusive option.  If you add it as the answer, I'll mark it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is going to be using the network-level control that comes with an ILB App Service Environment. If that's too pricey, try the IP restrictions feature on the public app service.